# Which files needs to be edited for implementing custom design for top menu

Tags: magento-1.8, navigation

I have been struggling in Magento for "How to implement custom Menu design" and which all files needs  to be edited for the same. Menu design is simple.

[Here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/) is what i am trying to replicate in Magento.

Please let me know guys which all files it is need to customize top menu.

Can any one please share any good tutorial or article on how Magento builds Top Menu navigation?

Thanks

Comment: check your theme folder template/page/html/topmenu.phtml

Answer (score 1):

In the default theme for 1.7 and 1.8 the main menu is rendered by this method: 
`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu::_getHtml`. This renders recursively the menu items added through the event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before`.
You can rewrite this method to add your custom html.
For versions before 1.7 the menu contained only the categories and it was rendered in the same way as above by `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

you should refer  [this link](http://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-change-the-header-of-magento-cms-page/)  to change magento header. This might help you.

Comment: This is not what i am looking for .. sorry

Comment: Please do not submit link-only answers.